# Is there a way to count the channels inside of a category in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to write a bot that will tell me the number of channels in a specific category.

```js
if (strMessage === "!outline") {
  var outlineSize;

  message.reply("There are " + outlineSize + " outlines currently hidden away. Type '?outline' to learn more about them.");
}
```

I'm trying to set `outlineSize` to the number of channels in the category (the category is always the same, hence the specific variable name). For example, if there are two channels I want `outlineSize` to equal 2.

I know that it has something to do with `CategoryChannelChildManager` in discord.js v14. However, I've found nothing that's been able to teach me how to use it. To be fair, I'm new to programming and JavaScript which is where I expect the main part of the problem lies.

Also note: There are a few similar questions on this site that pertain to this, but due to the always-changing nature of Discord's API I don't believe they've been accurate for over a year now and give me nothing but errors when I try them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the category channel by its ID and grab its `children` property. As you've mentioned it's a `CategoryChannelChildManager` so you will need to access its `cache` that returns a `Collection`. And finally, `Collection`s have a `size` property that returns the number of items in the given collection. That's what you'll need:

```js
let CATEGORY_ID = '813845582854001392';
let category = await client.channels.fetch(CATEGORY_ID);
let outlineSize = category.children.cache.size;

message.reply(`There are ${outlineSize} outlines currently hidden away. Type '?outline' to learn more about them.`);
```